# How do I automatically generate documentation/comments in Monodevelop?

Tags: c#, monodevelop, documentation-generation, xamarin-studio

Monodevelop automatically generates verbose documentation for functions and classes if "///" is typed in the appropriate place, upon typing the third '/'.

I want it to go over **all** of my code, though - I thought there was some button somewhere, and I looked around in the drop-down menus, tried right-clicking file names, etc.
I could not find such an option - does it not exist? I could not find a plugin that does that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. Your options are:

- Manually typing three slashes before each and every function
- Using an external tool

Online searches have not come up with any plugins for monodevelop that would do that, and the option does not exist in the vanilla IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use Edit-> Document buffer.

It will make /// comments for all your public methods/classes without any comment upon it in current file.

It won't work if you have // comment upon method/class or for protected/private elements.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea if there's a way to hotkey this for a specific function? Like click on function and do a hotkey to have it add this.